# Why is a hexagon such a stable shape for materials?

Tags: symmetry, material-science, stability

A hexagonal lattice is famously the shape of graphene, the source of the 2010 Nobel prize. The shape also shows up in beehives and in the basalt columns of Giant's Causeway in County Antrim.

[image: Fionn mac Cumhaill]
*"Causeway-code poet-4". Licensed under CC BY-SA 2.0 via Wikimedia Commons*

What makes hexagons so stable?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509063/why-does-nature-prefer-hexagons

Comment: It's worth nothing that the reason for the hexagonal structure is different in those three examples you give.

Answer (score 1):

**Hypothesis:** Considering transverse stress and strain, the hexagonal unit completely tiles the space within the structure without gaps and combined with this property, comes closest to a emulating a circle which most symmetrically distributes stress and load.